If Starliner returns safely on autopilot, can this still prove that it's safe? Could it be launched back up to the ISS again to complete its mission?
NASA is understandably cautious when it comes to risking the lives of their astronauts. But, I'm wondering if Starliner were to return successfully (albeit uncrewed) and in the process provide more empirical data about the reliability of the spacecraft, then could the test flight nevertheless succeed in establishing that Starliner is safe enough to advance to the status of an operational spacecraft?
In that case, perhaps they could turn Starliner around again, take up commander Zena Cardman and Stephanie Wilson (the two astronauts who will have to give up their spots on Crew 9), and return with Butch and Sunita as originally planned.

One flight does not ‘prove’ safety.

We don't hear the  slogan "If it's not Boeing, I'm not going" as much as we used to.

@JonCuster Yes, word count limits forced me to shorten "sufficiently safe" to just "safe".

"...and if nothing else goes wrong in the mean time..." The Starliner spacecraft has started to emit strange noises (there's an embedded audio recording of it in the article)

The malfunctioning thrusters are scheduled to burn up during re-entry. So no diagnostics there. The best NASA can do is to cut its losses and throw Starliner in the trash.

@TonyK I think that a new question "Have there been any notable examples of when NASA decided to cut its losses and cancel a project after a large amount had already been spent?" would be in order.

@uhoh: Space shuttle?

@TonyK c'mon now. I meant projects that were unfinished/unproven, not something that's flown 100+ successful missions.

@uhoh If only opinion-based answers were allowed. We could have so much fun answering "What's the cause of Starliner's mysterious sounds?"

The Space Shuttle is probably a better example of why you shouldn't assume something is safe just because it hasn't been a problem thus far.

In music performance, there's a saying that an amateur practises until they get it right; a professional practises until they can't get it wrong.  Maybe that's relevant here, too.

@SimonCrase You just neeed to take out that first "not".

@phil1008, turns out it was just boring old audio feedback, combined with non-linearities in the audio electronics.

@Mark So you would have us believe. :-)

A successful landing, even if all of the thrusters worked perfectly (except for the one that they deactivated), would only be one step towards planning a return to flight mission with crew. Boeing still has to study and understand what caused the thrusters to malfunction, come up with either a fix or software/procedure workaround, and perform whatever tests are required to convince NASA that Starliner is safe to return to ISS with or without crew.
It is unknown at this time if another uncrewed test flight will be required. Even if the next Starliner carries crew on its next flight, it is unknown if this would be a repeat of the CFT mission with two astronauts, or if Starliner would be put into rotation for its first contracted Commercial Crew mission carrying four astronauts. During the press conference announcing the plan, NASA managers did not rule out any of these possibilities.
With the Crew-9 launch expected to take place less than a month after Starliner returns, it seems virtually impossible that NASA would reverse course on its decision to launch Crew-9 with two astronauts leaving two empty seats for Butch Wilmore and Suni Williams. Whichever two astronauts launch on Crew 9 will be returning on the Dragon Crew-9 capsule, so if Wilmore and Williams return on a Starliner, Crew-9 would wind up with two empty on the return.

"Boeing still has to study and understand what caused the thrusters to malfunction" this is key. The same (or very similar) thruster failures happened on uncrewed demo-2 and the fact that they didn't successfully fix a known problem despite years of time is not a good look.

@Dragongeek - discussion during the press conference by Steve Stich (Boeing was conspicuously absent, reportedly not invited) was that they think it may have been a combination of things that happened, some of which were difficult (read between the lines - not impossible) to test, which is the heat radiated in the doghouses in a vacuum while thrusters are firing. One theory is the manual flying by Wilmore (partly for test, but I think also due to the problem) created more heat than the autonomous system would have. If so it sounds like they didn't test enough for all possible scenarios.

And you have to be able to fly it on manual, because if you can't the automation will break.

@Dragongeek: I dimly recall that thruster failure is not exactly a rare issue on many spacecraft? That’s why they have so much redundancy. Just like gyro failures or parachute failures …

Answer: No
from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Starliner

The Starliner capsule ... is reusable up to 10 times with a six-month turnaround time.

I don't think its going anywhere, anytime soon... even if it checks out A-OK.

Unknown
Starliner, even if it is recovered safely, will not be flying again anytime soon. Fact is, the issue is very complex, and while there are claims that the "root cause" has been discovered (weird behavior in teflon seals), the extremely large amount of testing leaves and general uncertainty strongly indicates that there isn't a simple and obvious fix.
More generally, there is uncertainty about the technical soundness of Starliner at a fundamental level: the first flight test, despite being a general failure, still got remarkably lucky as the post-flight investigation revealed serious issues, with NASA stating, "We could have lost a spacecraft twice during this mission". This second flight test was supposed to show that all the issues found had been fixed... but it turns out there were still more serious issues.
This led to the second uncrewed flight test, where there were also a bunch of technical issues and thruster failures just like on the current crew mission. The fact that Boeing, despite having two years apparently failed to fix a known problem and launched astronauts regardless is... not good.
My predictions
First, the timeline:

2024: Starliner will probably land safely autonomously (current plan is in September)
2025: Starliner Crew-1 is set to NET Aug, but I think this will almost certainly slip out of 2025
2026: If the Starliner program continues, this is where we will see Crew 1 at the absolute earliest

Personally, things aren't looking good for Starliner. My (outsider) read is that Boeing had to pull quite a bit and burn political capital to ensure the crewed flight took place after the failed first test flight and a second flight test which also didn't go so hot. In particular, the fact that there were known failures on the second flight that weren't comprehensively fixed ahead of this first crewed flight is a very bad look for the company.
I expect NASA to insist on a fourth flight test, uncrewed, before proceeding with fully operational crew flights. I really can't imagine anything else: Boeing has shown they are incapable of fixing known issues, and this entire circus has been quite the PR headache for everyone involved. If NASA/Boeing want to directly go into operational flights after all the failures, a lot of people are going to be asking a lot of hard questions about where tax dollars are being spent, and with all the negative media so far, it will be very hard to sell a "See, the crew demo capsule landed safely and any astronauts inside would've been fine!" into directly getting started with fully operational flights.

And note there are possible paths in which the capsule lands successfully but if there had been crew on board they wouldn't have survived.  It might slowly limp out of orbit (which they would do if possible to avoid it becoming debris) but beyond life support endurance.

@LorenPechtel Yeah, good point. There is also, of course, the option that Boeing decides to cut their losses and end the Starliner program. I am not sure how the payment structure is for NASA CC program (milestones?) but if they need to do another demo flight "out of pocket" for another ~410 million that demo-2 cost, that's a hefty sum for Boeing.

There's a limited supply of Atlas V boosters too. Theoretically Starliner can fly on other boosters but making that happen won't be quick or cheap.

@Dragongeek According to WP, NASA only pays for successful tests, so quitting makes sense if they don't think their remaining tests will succeed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Starliner#Background "To receive the full contract amount, each company would need to successfully complete an abort test, an uncrewed orbital flight test, a crewed orbital flight test, and six crewed missions to the ISS. However, NASA would not need to pay for any failed tests and was only required to purchase two crewed missions to the ISS from each company."

Irrespective of the problem, it would be quite a loss for humanity if Boeing pulled out of the almost completed program. Today's safety standards - which I enjoy very much and perfectly support - make certifying a new model very costly. This is very similar to planes - a new development costs a lot and takes much longer than it used to. From one side you would want new models to come, so, you would expect government support, otherwise, we might have a monopoly, from the other, knowing you WILL be paid, makes businesses abuse it. An example in my eyes would be the SLS.

@Mykola Definitely, although it is a bit worrying that Boeing has not published any intentions (that I am aware of) of going beyond Commercial Crew with Starliner or even continuing beyond the initially contracted scope. Unlike Crew Dragon, they have yet to book any non-NASA flights, nor made any serious offers to sell it to non-NASA customers.

MY prediction is that this thing blows up and that Boeing use this as an excuse to bow out of a race that they've very clearly lost.

@Dragongeek this would be the commercial department work - and my sympathies are more with the engineering department - although I understand both don't exist without each other, I value the engineering/designing/manufacturing part more. Plus, SpaceX has its own cheap-to-lunch Falcon rocket and it is hard to compete with them commercially in the private sector when the buyer is not willing to pay $$$ just to not allow monopoly and keep the industry running.

The thrusters are part of the discarded service module so a new launch would have new thrusters with potentially more problems than the current set.
Until Boeing can convince NASA that they fully understand — and have resolved — the thruster issues Starliner won't be flying crew.

This is the key point. If there is a fix for the thrusters, they will need to be tested on the ground, and in an unmanned test flight, before another crew test flight. The unmanned test will need to work those thrusters hard, and so will the manned test.
